# Display results of sub definitions in Behat?

Tags: behat

If I create a definition using the Behat steps, the results of the steps in the function aren't being displayed. I would like to display the results of all the steps not just the calling step.

eg:

The following code will only display

```
'Given I do something with "this"'
```

But I would also like to see

```
'When I search for "this"'
'Then I should see "this"'
```

features/dosomething.feature

```
Feature: Do something
  In order to do something
  As an admin user
  I need to do something

  @api
  Scenario: Do something
    Given I do something with "this"
```

features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php

```
/**
 * @When /^I do something with "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iDoSomethingWith($something) {
    $steps = array();
    $steps[] = new When('I search for "'. $something . '"');
    $steps[] = new Then('I should see "' . $something . '"');
    return($steps);
}
```